# recompiling audio from a movie source

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, movieclip, movie

Is it possible to recompile movie files to re-stream the audio so they all have the same volume level? We've got users submitting videos and to me it seems some are higher in volume whereas others are not, and they all have the same volume level on the controls, and **i'd like to standardize this so all movie files have the same volume levels**.

I was thinking of `ffmpeg` although I only have novice knowledge of this technology and haven't done my research in it yet.

Anyway if there's anything available I'd love to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg has a `loudnorm` filter that will normalize the audio to meet [EBU R128](https://tech.ebu.ch/loudness) recommendations. Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -af loudnorm out.mp4
```

A faster filter is `dynaudnorm` but this one may alter the audio shape a bit, or so I'm told.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -af dynaudnorm=r=0.5 out.mp4
```